# Recorrer diccionario en la plantilla

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Tengo la siguiente vista:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def ini (request):
    dic = {"nombre" : "Mauro", "apellido" : "London", "sexo" : "M"}
    return render(request, "ini.html", dic )
```

y el ini.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
 <body>
 <h1>Esto es una prueba {{ nombre }} {{ apellido }}</h1>
 <ul>
    {% for valor in dic %}
      <li>{{ dic[valor] }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
 </ul>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Mi pregunta: Veo que tanto la clave del diccionario "nombre" y "apellido" se imprimen si hago referencia directamente a ella...pero no se como imprimir el diccionario haciendo un recorrido desde un for. Lo hago como se hace en python pero me da error.

He probado con:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
 <body>
 <h1>Esto es una prueba {{ nombre }} {{ apellido }}</h1>
 <ul>
    {% for key, value in dic.items %}
      <li>{{ key }} : {{ value }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
 </ul>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

no da error pero no imprime nada....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Las claves del diccionario que pasas al argumento `context` de `render` en la vista son las variables que puedes usar en la plantilla. En otras palabras, cuando haces `{% for key, value in dic.items %}` es como si buscaras la clave `"dic"` en el diccionario `dic` pasado a `render`.

Lo que puedes hacer es simplemente pasar tu diccionario como valor de una clave de dicho diccionario:

### view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def ini(request):
    dic = {"nombre" : "Mauro", "apellido" : "London", "sexo" : "M"}
    return render(request, 'ini.html', context={"dic": dic})
```

### ini.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<body>
    <h1>Esto es una prueba {{ dic.nombre }} {{ dic.apellido }}</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for key, value in dic.items %}
        <li>{{ key }} : {{ value }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Con esto debes obtener lo que buscas:

> ## Esto es una prueba Mauro London
>
> - nombre : Mauro
> - apellido : London
> - sexo : M

---

Comment: Excelente FJSevilla ya entendí como se hace. He querido aprender paso a paso antes de meterme de lleno con las conexiones a Base de datos....

Comment: Disculpen de antemano si doy click a algo que no debo es que soy nuevo en stackoverflow